# Soundcloud API /stream returns 403 in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: firefox, soundcloud

I am trying to use the Soundcloud API. I make a request backend which works fine. I get the track id and with that i call api.soundcloud.com/tracks/242264498/stream?client_id=[REMOVED]. That link works fine in both Chrome and Firefox. However, when using it with jQuery/HTML it seems to fail in Firefox.

Request:

```
$(".jukebox").prop("src", 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+track_id+'/stream?client_id=2487d5f911c4c44f0882c063ec104332').trigger('play');
```

Response (ONLY Firefox):

```
GET https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/C21H6loBzYez.128.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 23ms]
```

Running this in Firefox console plays the track for less than 1 second. I can hear it "stutter". Then it gives the 403.

```
$(".jukebox").prop("src", 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+242264498+'/stream?client_id=2487d5f911c4c44f0882c063ec104332').trigger('play');
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<audio class="audio_file jukebox" controls preload="auto" data-volume="0.25"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your code. And it worked fine even in firefox too.

```
https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/C21H6loBzYez.128.mp3
```

This url  will simply not work, it needs access token id and other GET parameters. If SoundCloud is redirecting you to this url (with no GET parameters such as access token id and any others) then it may be something with SoundCloud as its not a 'normal' behavior.

I suggest you to re-test your code as it worked fine for me.